# Get table does not exist error, when trying to insert into table from a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm attempting to use a trigger to fill values of another table. The trigger watches for insert on table ratings and updates the values of another table, `top5restaurants`. I haven't figured out how to maintain only the `top 5` in `top5restaurants`, I don't know how to limit a table to a certain number of entries. But right now I can't seem to do anything to `top5restaurants` from within the trigger.

```
drop view top_rest;

create view top_rest (rid, rat) 
as
    (select distinct rid, max(stars) 
     from rating
     group by rid);

drop table top5restaurants;

create table top5restaurants(rid int);

insert into top5restaurants(rid)
    select rid from top_rest
    where rownum <= 5
    order by rat asc;

create or replace trigger top5_trigger
after insert on ratings
for each row
    declare top5 top5restaurants%rowtype;

    cursor top5_cursor is
    select rid from top_rest
    where rownum <=5
    order by rat;
    begin
    for record in top5_cursor
    loop

        fetch top5_cursor into top5; 
        insert into top5restaurants values(top5);
    end loop;
    end;
    /
--    
--
begin
update_reviews('Jade Court','Sarah M.', 4, '08/17/2017');
update_reviews('Shanghai Terrace','Cameron J.', 5, '08/17/2017');
update_reviews('Rangoli','Vivek T.',3,'09/17/2017');
update_reviews('Shanghai Inn','Audrey M.',2,'07/08/2017');
update_reviews('Cumin','Cameron J.', 2, '09/17/2017');
end;
/    
select * from top5restaurants;
insert into top5restaurants values(184);
```

However, the table does exist and I can run queries on it and it returns the data I inserted when I created the table. I can also insert values. Not sure why I get table not found error when using a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the difference in table names(answer by Littlefoot) in the `trigger` and `view`, You have not used the `rowtype` collection properly while inserting the data.

you must remove the brackets:

replace

```
insert into top5restaurants values(top5);
```

with

```
insert into top5restaurants values top5;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all tables involved, but - what is obvious, is that **view** is created as

```
create view top_rest ... from rating
                              ------
```

while **trigger** is created as

```
after insert on ratings
                -------
                      ^
                      s?
```

Which one is it? `rating` or `ratings`?

Comment: its rating, sorry.